# std::promise в C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Изучаю многопоточность в C++. Никак не могу понять, что такое `std::promise`, для чего он нужен и почему так называется? Объясните, пожалуйста. Нагуглить чего-то толкового не получилось.

Comment: [Почитайте](http://scrutator.me/post/2012/06/03/parallel-world-p2.aspx), может поможет.

Answer (score 7):

Обещание (`promise`) - это ровно 1/2 механизма `promise-future`. Несмотря на то, что обещания и фьючерсы существуют всегда только парой и отдельно друг от друга использоваться не могут, первая часть этой пары особой известностью не пользуется. Если про фьючерс любая книжка по STL подробно рассказывает, то про обещание упоминает в лучшем случае мельком (а чаще вообще не упоминает).

Объясняется это просто - работа непосредственно с потоком и обещанием полностью закрыта высокоуровневой оберткой `async`, и фьючерсы всегда описывают именно в контексте использования функции `async`. В этом есть смысл, потому что иметь дело непосредственно с обещанием программисту приходится только в том редком случае, когда его не устраивает стандартный `async`, и он вынужден писать его аналог вручную.

Вот так выглядит простейший случай использования фьючерса с `async`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  auto ThreadFunc = []() -> const char* { return "S novym godom!"; };  // Функция потока

  // Создать поток и получить связанный с ним фьючерс
  auto f = async(ThreadFunc);

  // Ожидать завершения потока и получит результат из фьючерса
  string s = f.get();

  cout << s;
  return 0;
}
```

А теперь сделаем то же самое без `async`, через базовые средства поток-обещание:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  promise<const char*> p;  // Создать обещание...
  future<const char*> f = p.get_future();  // ...и получить связанный с ним фьючерс

  auto ThreadFunc = [&p] () { p.set_value("S novym godom!"); };  // Функция потока

  // Запустить поток
  thread t(ThreadFunc);

  // Ожидать завершения потока и получит результат из фьючерса
  string s = f.get();

  cout << s;
  return 0;
}
```

Подводя итог: связанная пара `promise-future` образует механизм межпоточного взаимодействия, который позволяет передать результат выполнения потока (или исключение, выброшенное в потоке) в вызывающий поток. Механизм одноразовый, то есть передать получится только результат. Для многократной передачи данных нужно использовать другие средства.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ "freim" - очень обстоятельный и интересный, хотелось бы добавить еще, для полного понимания картинки.
"promise" - это то куда ИСПОЛНИТЕЛЬ положит результат
"future" - это то откуда ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЬ заберет результат

Как Вы понимаете, исполнитель и потребитель будут находиться в разных потоках. А через магию promise-future результат будет передан из одного потока в другой.

В дополнение, я бы добавил от себя: promise - хранит результат, а future - работает потоком потребителя чтобы этот результат передать (может стопорнуть поток).

Советую глянуть первоисточник на YouTube (люди которые это реализовали): 
[CppCon 2014: Hartmut Kaiser "Asynchronous Computation in C++"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xyztU__yys&t=1249s)